# How to use an if statement in CSS, or solve it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> Demo at bottom of page

So I have a div that by default has opacity 0, let's call it #myDiv.

When the user hovers over #myDiv, the opacity changes to 1.

```
#myDiv {
  opacity: 0;
}

#myDiv:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Now I have a `<hr/>` tag inside the div that's by default `width: 0;`, for example like so:

```
hr {
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

After the user hovers the #myDiv, it will transition to having 100% width, like this:

```
#myDiv:hover hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now I also have a script on this website that checks for mobile users, because those won't trigger the hover effect. So it will check if the div is visible on the screen and will set the opacity to 1.

Now I want to be able to trigger the `<hr/>` effects on mobile, I thought maybe it would be possible to use an if statement in css but I don't think that's possible. What I have in mind is something like:

```
if (#myDiv.opacity == 1) {
  hr {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

But this cannot be done with css, is this possible with Javascript or what would be the best solution here?

I dont have a lot of experience with JavaScript.

To view a demo on desktop, see:
[Go to My Work and hover over project](https://mrdylan123.github.io/portfolio)

How can I achieve this on mobile?

Comment: how about using `scss` ?

Comment: you will want to have a look over media queries (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: so you have a JS script that checks if the #myDiv is inview and changes the opacity, why cant this script also trigger the animation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using media queries and you can also remove your js for the opacity ;)

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  #myDiv {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  #myDiv hr {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Edit**: considering that you also need to check if is in view, in you js instead of setting opacity to 1, add a class to #myDiv and change the css like this:

```
hr {
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#myDiv {
  opacity: 0;
}

#myDiv:hover, #myDiv.mobile {
  opacity: 1;
}

#myDiv:hover hr, #myDiv.mobile hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

in this way you will handle the change in the same css way as desktop, only adding a class ;)

Comment: The js is used to also detect if the div is actually visible on the screen. If you take a look at the link and inspect element you can see the opacity only changes when you scroll to it.

Comment: Im trying to add the class, as follow:
(isScrolledIntoView(tile1)) ? $(caption1).classList.add("project-mobile")
However this raises errors, "cannot read property 'add' of undefined", while at the top i say: var caption1 = document.getElementById('caption1'), which also exists in my html

Comment: are you using jquery? in this case you only have to do somethign like `$('#caption1').addClass('project-mobile');` if you are using vanilla js you need to do something like `caption1.className += ' project-mobile';`

Comment: P.s. suggestion: if you adopt a framework, use it, don't mix vanilla and the framework, it makes the code confusing... so, for instance, if you use jquery don't do `document.querySelector('#blabla')` or `document.getElementById('blabla')` simple call `$('#blabla')` ;)

Comment: Yes, I have managed to fix it now. It was indeed jquery. I have now done it this way:  

`(isScrolledIntoView(tile1)) ? $('#caption1').addClass("project-mobile") : $("#caption1").removeClass("project-mobile");`  

 and it finally works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not use if statements in plain CSS. You can [use a mediaquery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for basic detection:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  hr {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

767pixels is one less than a iPad. You can of cource change this to a settings you like.

Alternatively, you can do this via javascript. You have to look for a snippet that checks if you are a mobile user, if so -> add the class `isMobile` to you `<body />`. Now you can do this:

```
.isMobile hr {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Based on your added comment about 'only when in view', you can use javascript to detect if the element is in the view (this has to be done with javascript). There are plenty snippets to be found. You can use the same trick, and add a class like `isInView`.

---

In both cases I let CSS do the actual changes, JS is just an assist. This is because CSS does styling, not JS. And this way you let css know what it has to do.

Comment: But the width only has to be added when #myDiv is in the view, so how will that be achieved?

Comment: expanded my answer, see the last paragraph above the line

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery. If this does not work comment please so I can assist you.. I am not behind a desktop atm

```
if ($('.test').css('opacity') === '1') {
    $("hr").css("width", "100%");
}
```